# How do I delete a nested array without knowing its index?

Tags: javascript, arrays, nested, react-redux, google-cloud-firestore

I have nested array as a form of map in array, but when I need to delete one of them, I don't know how to pick up exact one that I need to remove.

Firebase database - cloud:

[image: image link]

```
getFirestore()
  .collection("projects")
  .doc(projectId)
  .update({
      keyResults: getFirestore().FieldValue.arrayRemove({ ????? })
   })
```

The above code didn't work.

I'd like to remove second one from `keyResults` array.

Comment: If you don't know its index, what **do** you know about the item you want to delete? Note that there is no item with `id: 2` in the screenshot you shared, so that won't work.

Comment: If you don't know how to fully specify the item to remove from the array, you will have to write code to read the document, find the item in the array you want to remove using whatever information you have, remove that item from the array in memory, then write the contents of the document back to the database.  You won't be able to do this in a single operation.

Comment: I am sorry. I edited my question. Thank you for your kind conments

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understood correctly but why not use [Array.splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Array/splice) ?

```
const fireStore = getFirestore()
const keyResults = fireStore.FieldValue
      keyResults.splice(1, 1)

fireStore
.collection("projects")
.doc(projectId)
.update({keyResults})
```